# understanding Let scope

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, variable-declaration

My assumption with code is that for the second `let x` the code above it is in the temporal dead zone. Hence should not throw error.

**Code**

```js
function f(condition, x) {
  if (condition) {
    let x = 100;
    return x;
  }
  let x = 30; // <---- throw error

  return x;
}

f(true, 1);
```

Comment: `let` is "block scoped" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: i know let is block-scoped

Comment: Read about hoisting in Javascript so you can understand which codes fail of your examples.

Comment: …meaning your `if() {   }` statement creates a block where `x` has not yet been defined.

Comment: so what's the confusion @aWebDeveloper?

Comment: @Dez - there is no hoisting in the code snippets - well, NOW there is :p

Comment: Seen as a function parameters have no specific type, eg. const let, for backwards compatibility it will most likely act like a var,.. var's are allowed to be redeclared.

Comment: by the way ... the first code doesn't throw an error

Comment: @JaromandaX in code 2 how is re-declare allowed  and in code 3 why isn't re-declare allowed if let is block-scoped

Comment: @JaromandaX you are right.. i have updated the code 1

Comment: In code 2 `x` is blocked scoped to the if. In code 3 your redeclaring `x` that has already in the function scope by passing it as an arg

Comment: code 2 ... let inside block is allowed ... code 3 ... let is in the same block scope as argument x

Comment: Check the scopes,  `var let` in the same scope will error.  but a `var let` in different scopes is fine.  In a nutshell, a `let / const` does not work in the same scope.

Comment: Your edit, you can take out the `if condition` as that's not what's causing the issue.  You are re declaring the the parameter x, in the same scope.  So your doing a `var let`.. error.  And could just be shortened to `function f(x) { let x = 30; }`

Comment: `temporal dead zone` it would be if you never declared a parameter `x`..

Answer (score 3):

Well the problem here is that you are redeclaring the same variable `x` twice in the same `function`, so the variable `x` will be hoisted.

```
  if (condition) {
    //This x declaration is fine as it wasn't preceded with any others declaration inside the same block scope
    let x = 100;
    return x;
  }
  //Now this second x declaration will cause the hoisting problem 
  let x = 30; // <---- throw error
```

Here the second `let x = 30;` declaration is hoisting the `x` variable in your `function` scope. So conclusion is that you can't declare the same variable more than once in the same scope.

For further reading about varaible hoisting in Javascript you can check:

- [MDN **Hoisting**
  reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).
- [**A guide to JavaScript variable hoisting  with let and const** article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-variable-hoisting-differentiating-between-var-let-and-const-in-es6-f1a70bb43d)

Comment: You can take out the `if (condition)` bit, as that's not the `x` it's complaining about. eg. this is fine `{let x = 0; { let x = 0; }}`

Comment: This is wrong. There is no hoisting with `let`/`const`. The issue is caused by the passed in argument `x`, which is in the same scope like the second `let` declaration. `let`/`const` means that you can only bind a name (`x`) once within the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

Issues seem to be with **x** already being a function parameter having the same scope as the outer **x**. If i change function parameter **x** with **y**, the code works fine.

**Code**

```js
function f(condition, y) {
  if (condition) {
    let x = 100;
    return x;
  }
  let x = 30; // <---- doesnt throw error

  return x;
}

f(true, 1);
```